# Hiberanate getting null from SQL field that have comma seperated values in it

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a table in this

```
ID   NAME
1    a,b
2     c
3    d,e
```

but when i am getting list using criteria.list() method of hibernate.
It's giving me list like

```
[1,null,2,c,3,null]
```

I don't want null values as I don't have null in that field

Code is:

```
        Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(RuleLookupData.class);
        List<List<String>> name = new ArrayList<>();
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ne(BaseConstants.STATUS, StateEnum.DELETED));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ruleLookUpTable.id",tableId));
        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
        for(int i=1;i<=20;i++){
            projectionList.add(Projections.property("strParam"+i));
        }
        //criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
        List<Object> list = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Without more info, especially on the mapping, the actual table layout, the criteria you're using etc. it's hard to say.

Comment: show the criteria creation in its entierety and also the entity mapping

Comment: @Vpn_talent add the code to your question. no code in comments please.

Comment: @Vpn_talent Have you found a solution for this??